# Change value of a form stored in a variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, post

How do you change the value of an input field of a form that is never printed to the HTML of the page? (I don't want to add it to the html of the page)

I'm not sure if I even have to use the $form notation vs. form

I'd like to change the value of the myName input field before submitting the form.

```
var $form = $('<form/>', {
                      method: 'post', 
                      id: 'form1', 
                      name: 'form1', 
                      action: 'example.example'
                      }); 

$form.append($('<input/>', {name: 'myName', value: 'myValue', type: 'hidden'}));      

$form.submit()
```

Comment: `$form` is already in DOM. Check it with firebug in Firefox.

Comment: sorry, thought DOM and HTML structure of the page are the same thing. It's not added to the HTML structure and I don't want to add it there.

Comment: get that element in some JS variable and then change value using `val()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should assign new input to a variable, and then use that variable to change value:

```
var $form = $('<form/>', {
                  method: 'post', 
                  id: 'form1', 
                  name: 'form1', 
                  action: 'example.example'
                  }); 

var inp = $('<input/>', {name: 'myName', value: 'myValue', type: 'hidden'});
$form.append(inp);      

$(inp).val('something else');

$form.submit()
```

Comment: Thank you, very straightforward